# Redirecting virtual subdomain to another file

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdomain, virtualhost, wildcard-subdomain

i've virtual subdomains like http://[username].website.com

Now when visited this url i want to show the content of page index2.php instead of index.php so content returned will be different when visited index page http://website.com and http://[username].website.com

I've tried by editing the htaccess file without success.
Which conditions should i define on the file?

see the code i've used by placing the files on a folder called "subdomain" but it's not working fine

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.website\.com
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/subdomains/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: What about using Apache's mod_userdir?  Assuming you're running Apache, that is.

Comment: What did you try? Please show your code...

Comment: Hi, see above i've pasted the code